# Calculating frequency of a number in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a big dataset, on film ratings (1 - 10) and would like to get the distribution of the ratings. I also have 0s in the dataset, but those are in reality NAs, but I need them as 0s for later in the project (trying to build a recommendation system).

**Sample Data**

`User.ID     60392452   60502258    60915544    60928336    60930535    60934417    60938455    60959037    60976845
1   26  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   51  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   91  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   99  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   114 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   125 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   165 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   9
8   243 0   0   10  0   0   0   0   0   0`

Ok, it's not so readable, but User ID column is "26", "51" etc. The movies, which are indicated by codes, are "60392452" etc and are the column headers.

As a start, I used the following code:

`table(mod_dataset)`

but I got an error message:

`Error in table(mod_dataset) : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements`

What is the equivalent of table for "big data" ?

Comment: Please post your sample data set along with sample of output, without that it is NOT clear.

Comment: You probably don't have 2^31 actual elements in your data - that would be a lot of film ratings.  I might suggest looking for what's causing there to appear to be so many elements...that's a starting point for debugging.

Comment: I think, `2^31` is too big :D

Comment: @andrew_reece: probably all the zeros I'm guessing (which really means they didn't watch the movie), so will keep it as NA for now.

Comment: @TheStatisticianMagician, off course you need to put only sample few lines data which is near to your actual data and sample few lines expected data to give clear picture of your question.

Comment: What is your desired output? It is not very clear from the question?

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure whether this answers your question, but it's a way to table the ratings on a column by column basis.

```
res <- sapply(mod_dataset[-1], function(x) table(factor(x, levels = 0:10)))
inx <- apply(res, 1, function(x) all(x == 0))
res[!inx, ]
```

**Data** in `dput`format.

```
mod_dataset <-
structure(list(User.ID = c(26L, 51L, 91L, 99L, 114L, 125L, 165L, 
243L), X60392452 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X60502258 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X60915544 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 10L), X60928336 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    X60930535 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X60934417 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X60938455 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), X60959037 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), X60976845 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```